# How to use java.util.GZIPOutputStream or any other to store multiple records as single file where each records are zipped individually?

Tags: java

How to use java.util.GZIPOutputStream or any other to store multiple records as single file where each records are zipped individually?

That is required for seek file for individual record and unzip that only.

I have read HBase doing same thing for hfile. But am getting problem with record wise zip in single file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream`. Before writing a new 'record', call `ZipOuputStream.putNextEntry` to indicate that you want to write the next record, and pass in a `ZipEntry` as the argument, with the filename you want to set for the next record.

Comment: Is there any other alternatives.... i have 10-20 no. of files and total size will be 25-30 MB(without compression)(as mail size restriction).

I have not tested with this but got some information as it will be ~50% slow compare to normal write. i need speed as well good compression.

I have still to test read and write performance with java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.

Thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: Before your suggestion i think to apply as HBase did with its hfile(storeFile). where file format is :

(DATA1 DATA2 DATA3... | Meta Data | Trailer).

where DATA1, DATA2... are my different part of mail and Meta will hold the offset of each DATA start position. and single trailer is long value that will hold offset of whole Meta start position.
I have program that can easily write/read content of single mail. But have to apply compression on each data. except Meta and Trailer.

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to add some boundary frames between the outputs from multiple GZipOutputStreams - especially if you know the length of the (uncompressed) data, you can write the length of the next section in the file before the data, and when you read it back, make sure that GZipInputStream can only read that many bytes - by passing it your own subclass of FilterInputStream that will not read more bytes than that and pretend that there's an end-of-file after that.

Comment: Hi Erwin,
I want to store more than one file into single file in below format:
File1|File2|File3....|Meta|Trailer
where Fiile1, File2... is the content of respective files and Meta hold the (version,no. of files), filename length, filename, offset, size of each file, and trailer hold the offset of meta starting.

I can able to combine and read normal file. but can't understand how could i use GzipOutputStream/GzipInputStream with this.

If you can give me some example/skeleton code then will be better for me. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Use [ZipOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) with [ZipEntry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html) for each record.

You should be able to extract particular records (ZipEntry) when you want to without having to unzip the whole file.

Comment: Thanks Manvendra...
Is there any other alternative to get fast read/write as well good compression. I have to use this to store single mail as a single compressed file. where each mail in average 10-20 no. of different chunks/contents and total size will be ~30 MB.